# Are there more than 20 million pieces of art in London's galleries?

Tags: united-kingdom, culture

[This video](https://vimeo.com/179957846) claims that there are more than 20 million pieces of art in London's galleries.

The video is an attempt to see all the art in London in a single day. The protagonist in the video got to sample 13 galleries out of 92. [The story](http://www.gizmodo.co.uk/2016/08/trying-to-see-all-the-art-in-all-the-museums-in-london-in-one-day-looks-like-a-fun-time/) reports the video's claim that:

> Alex Gorosh visited 13 museums in London, saw more than 140,000 works of art, and walked more than 22 miles in one day in an attempt to see all the art there is to see in London. He didn’t even see more than one per cent of the art in the city. That’s because London has 92 museums, and **more than 20 million works of art**.

Is it true that there are more than 20 million works of art in London's galleries?

Comment: Britain spent a *lot* of time looting stuff from every corner of their Empire in the few centuries of its heyday. Most of the artifacts ended up in London one way or another.

Comment: There will be many more pieces of art in the galleries' and museums' storage than there are on display.

Comment: The British Museum alone boasts 8,000,000 potential exhibits, and London contains many more museums. That makes it sound pretty plausible.

Comment: Arguably [more than 92 museums.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_museums_in_London). That's before we start counting art galleries.

Comment: @Shadur Most of london's art is not looted archeological antiquities.